# Send debug output to terminal multiplexer

Tags: bash, debugging, stderr

Given a shell script (bash in this example), one can use the `set -x` or `-x` passed to bash or other supporting shells to generate debug output.

I know how to redirect said output to a file `./script.sh 2> out.log` or `bash -x script.sh 2> out.log`.

But how to send stderr to a terminal multiplexer, like `screen` or `tmux`?

Mainly useful when script change the way the terminal is displayed(TUI), so sending stderr enable more comfortable debugging in another window/terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke `tty` in the terminal you want to send something to. It will print e.g. `/dev/pts/3` Then redirect anything you want to this file, possibly from another terminal. Like this:

```
bash -x script.sh 2> /dev/pts/3
```

This works with `tmux`, `screen`, separate terminal emulators or ttys (where you are logged in). Invoke `tty` in one shell and redirect/print to whatever it says from the other.

I use similar approach to debug my pipelines. Example:

```
foo | tee /dev/pts2 | filter1 | tee /dev/pts3 | filter2
```

---

tmux command `display '#{pane_tty}'` will print `/dev/pts/3` or so in the status line. This is useful if there's no shell in the target pane (so you cannot easily run `tty` there). Select the pane so it's current, hit <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>, type the command and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: so i just do `cat /dev/pts/3` in a loop, inside a tmux/screen session? (need to continuously see the debug output)

Comment: Thanks for the edit on your post. Seems to work :), also found that i could use `ps ax | grep $$ | awk '{ print $2 }'` inside the wanted pane in tmux, and then pipe to it like in your example. (feel free to add this method to your answer too)

Comment: @NordineLotfi Don't `cat`. Spawn two terminals, two shells; it doesn't matter if with `tmux`, `screen`, separate terminal emulators or ttys. Invoke `tty` in one and redirect/print to whatever it says from the other.

Comment: yeah, forgot that screen/tmux spawn their own shell instance :D. Got it.